# I have an odd variable that is showing the entire columns contents

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have modified a public script to work with the expiration dates in a spread sheet.  I wanted to add information from another column to help out with details.  The other variables all do as I expect but when adding the variable"model" it outputs all of the content that is on that column regardless of row.

```
function checkReminder() {
// get the spreadsheet object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// set the first sheet as active
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
// fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// figure out what the last row is
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
// is the headers, so start with row 2
var startRow = 2;

// grab column 8 (the 'days left' column) 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,8,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var days_left_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the name column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the model column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var model = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop over the days left values
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
if(days_left <= 60) {
  // if it's less than 60 days until due date.
  var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];

  msg = msg + ""+reminder_name+" Watchguard model "+model+" is due in 
"+days_left+" days.\n";
  warning_count++;
 }
 }

if(warning_count) {
MailApp.sendEmail("James@mccnet.com, jamesmccnet@gmail.com", 
    "Watchguard Expiration List", msg);
}


};
```

I get output that looks like this 
Metal Specialties, Inc Watchguard WGD-WG026063,WGD-WG25003,XTM
25,WGD-WG026583,XTM 26-W,AP 300,AP 200,AP 200,AP 200,WGD-WG026063,XTM
25,M440,WGD-WGT30061-US,AP 300,WGD-WG026583,AP 200,XTM 26,WG-WGM20083,AP
200,WGD-WG002503,WGD-WG002503,T30-W,AP 200,XTM
26-W,M400,WGD-WGAP3003,WGD-WG515063,WGD-WG330083,WGD-WG515063,XTM
515,WGD-WG330063,XTM 330,M300,T30-W,T30-W,WGD-WG330063,WG-WGM20083,AP
300,T30-W,T10-W,WGD-WGT30033-US,WGD-WGT31033-US,AP
300,T30-W,WGD-WFT31033-US,T30-W,T30-W,T30-W,T30-W,T30-W,MCA-SG560U-MTU,WGD-WG330063,WGD-WG330063,WGD-WG330063,WGD-WG330063,T30-W,WGD-WG330083,T30,WGD-WG330063,AP

300,T30-W,T30-W,T30-W,WGD-WGT31033-US,AP
320,WGD-WGA32443,WGD-WGT31033-US,T30-W,T10-W,AP 320,T30,WGD-WGAP3001,AP
102,AP 200,AP 200,AP 200,AP 200,AP 200,AP 200,AP 200,AP 200,AP 200,AP
200,AP
200,M200,T30-W,T30-W,watchguard
?,WGD-WG002503,WGD-WG002503,WGD-WG002503,WGD-WG002503,WGD-WG026051,WGD-WG25003,WGD-WG330083,WGD-WGAP3001,WGD-WGT31031-US

is due in  days.

It should look like this

Metal Specialties, Inc Watchguard model WGD-WGT31031-US is due in  days.

Comment: I would also like it to ignore the expired ones or state that they are expired.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is just dumping the the whole `model` array value instead of looping the values like `var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];` and `var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];`

Add the index to the `model`:

```
function checkReminder() {
...
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
  ...

   // Update model to only display the current row value
    msg = msg + ""+reminder_name+" Watchguard model "+model[i][0]+" is due in "+days_left+" days.\n";
    warning_count++;
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you wouldnt happen to also know how to get it to ignore or state expired if it comes the days left is blank?

Comment: Adjust your `if(days_left <= 60)` statement to make it do what you want it to do. Either ignore it or output a different string. [if...else/else if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) javascript docs